# Host-named Site Collections and Top Navigation bar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, top-link-bar, host-named

I have created a top navigation bar by implementing PortalSiteMapProvider and deploy it by a web scoped feature. if I create usual Site Collections Path-based SC it works and everything is ok, but if I create a Host-named site collection it generates

System.Web.HttpException the siteMapProvider MyTestTopNavProvider cannot not be found.

I have checked web.config file the provider is there.

thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this is another case where the error is not indicative of the real problem. Could you give an example of a site collection address that works and one that does not?

Comment: Hi, I solved this problem by adding host header to all host-named site collections on the web application. but I think it cannot be a good solution.